# Problema al evaluar dos Strings en Rust

Tags: rust

Tengo una función que evalua si una palabra es un palindromo:

Esta función retorna un bool, y tiene por parametro un objeto String (llamado *text*), el cuerpo de la función es el crear otro objeto String (llamado *palindrome*) e iterarlo para que la palabra quede al revés y retornar la función .eq()

El problema es la función .eq(), siempre que comparo la frase original (*text*) con el palindromo (*palindrome*), me retorna siempre un **false**, no importa qué escriba, así sea una letra como la "a". ¿Cómo puedo comparar los dos objetos Strings sin que siempre me salga **false**?

```
fn is_palindrome(text: String) -> bool {
    let mut palindrome: String = String::new();

    for i in text.chars().rev() {
        palindrome.push(i);
    }

    palindrome.eq(&text)

}
```

Ejemplo de entrada:

```
"ojo"
```

Retorno de la función:

```
false
```

¿Cómo es posible que "ojo" == "ojo" sea false? Ya puse println!() para saber si palindrome no había iterado bien todos los caracteres, pero es exactemente la misma palabra que text.

**Actualización**

Probando diferentes metodos, encontré que se debe porque a la hora de hacer la entrada por teclado usando:

```
let mut original: String = String::new();
std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut original).unwrap();
```

por alguna razón se creaba un whitespace y quedaba del tipo: "ojo ", y lo sé porque al usar la función trim(), me retornaba true por fin

Les dejo el codigo completo que daba error y el arreglado:

Con error:

```
fn is_palindrome(text: String) -> bool {
    let mut palindrome: String = String::new();

    for i in text.chars().rev() {
        palindrome.push(i);
    }

    return palindrome.eq(&text);

}

fn main() {
    let mut original: String = String::new();
    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut original).unwrap();
    println!("{}", is_palindrome(original));
}
```

Arreglado:

```
fn is_palindrome(text: String) -> bool {
    let mut palindrome: String = String::new();

    for i in text.chars().rev() {
        palindrome.push(i);
    }

    return palindrome.eq(&text);
}

fn main() {
    let mut original: String = String::new();
    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut original).unwrap();
    original = original.trim().to_string();
    println!("{}", is_palindrome(original));
}
```

Comment: Puedes agregar la porción de codigo desde la cual: 1) Se declara el argumento que le esta pasando a la invocación de `is_palindrome` 2) La declaración de la variable en la que está recibiendo el valor devuelto por `is_palindrome` tras la invocación 3) La sentencia de asignación misma del resultado de la invocación de `is_palindrome` a la variable `bool` declarada en (2) ?

Comment: Estás tratando de comparar un valor de cadena (`palindrome`) con una referencia a memoria (`&text` es una referencia a memoria). Eso siempre dará `false`.